# How to simultaneously play/stream a video and save it?

Tags: android, iphone, ios

I'm working on an iOS and Android app that allows the user to stream/play videos.

I would like to create an offline mode that gives the user the ability to play an already-saved video. To do so, I would like the app to save locally the currently played video if the user has a WiFi connection.
To do that, I would need a mechanism to read and save at the same time a video.

Any ideas to do that on iOS or/and Android?

Comment: Doesn't saving videos from some of the bigger websites violate the TOS?

Comment: you can write to a file and read it at the same time.

Comment: i don't see how a tos that says that you can watch it but not save it is even legal. also, the matter is not relevant to the technical question.

Comment: @ njzk2 - Thanks! I've heard about this solution, did you give it already a try? Because I never talked to anyone who successfully did it. It looks like there are some issues with the iOS player to handle  the EOF event. I don't know about Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> read and save at the same time

I guess you would have to span two different threads : one to read, and another to save.
And have the 'read' method try to get data from cache before downloading it.

on iPhone, possible duplicates :

- [Play video from cache in iphone programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402579/play-video-from-cache-in-iphone-programatically)
- [Simultaneously stream and save a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907230/simultaneously-stream-and-save-a-video)

The method described in these answers - caching download on disk, and read video from that file - should be the same for Android.